# How can I map a route with locked controller parameter values in ASP.Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a generic ASP.Net Core controller where I want it to perform a different operation based on the route.  My idea was to map different routes to use the same controller, where each mapping would set a different mode based on the route.  http://Website/Route1 would map to Mode1 and http://Website/Route2 would map to Mode2

```
            routes.MapRoute(
name: “Route1”,
template: “Route1” + "/{*queryParameters}",
defaults: new { controller = "GenericProcess", action = "RunGenericProcess", mode = “Mode1”, }
);


            routes.MapRoute(
name: “Route2”,
template: “Route2” + "/{*queryParameters}",
defaults: new { controller = "GenericProcess", action = "RunGenericProcess", mode = “Mode2”, }
);
```

This works when the user does not provide a mode parameter, but anyone can bypass the values I have set as defaults by explicitly providing a mode parameter.

http://Website/Route1/?mode=Mode2

Is there any way for me to specify hard values to a route mapping, instead of defaults that can be overridden?  Is there another way for me to accomplish my end goal, which is to build a multi purpose controller that lets me specify a mode based on the route?

Comment: What do you mean by `mode`? Share us the defination for the controller.

Comment: @TaoZhou, just imagine a switch statement on the mode inside the controller action.  I want to be able to specify the mode parameter based on the route, without giving the user the ability to set a mode with a route that I did not intend.

Answer (score 0):

Try code below with asp.net core mvc netcoreapp2.2.

1. `Startup.cs`

   ```
       app.UseMvc(routes =>
       {
           routes.MapRoute(
               name: "default",
               template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
           routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Route1",
               template: "Route1" +"/{*queryParameters}",
               defaults: new { controller = "GenericProcess", action = "RunGenericProcess", mode = "Mode1", }
               );


           routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Route2",
               template: "Route2" +"/{*queryParameters}",
               defaults: new { controller = "GenericProcess", action = "RunGenericProcess", mode = "Mode2", }
               );
       });
   ```
2. `Controller`

   ```
   public class GenericProcessController : Controller
   {
           public IActionResult RunGenericProcess(string mode)
           {
           return Ok(mode);
           }
   }
   ```

Comment: With this code I can still use “website/Route1/?mode=Mode2” and it will return “Mode2”, which is what I am trying to avoid.  I don’t want the use to be able to control the mode parameter.

Comment: @Eric Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? I fail to reproduce your issue with these code.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question but in my humble opinion and experience this isn't the best thing to do. I could imagine your "mode" in the URL would lead to some action thus you're essentially coding the action in the query string. It would be better to use attribute routing and have one controller per action which will make it easier to read, test and maintain. This concepts follows the Single responsibility principle (lookup SOLID principles).

All the best to your coding adventures :-)

Comment: I do try to stick with SOLID principals when writing line of business code, but this is more of a re-usable architectural component that I can take advantage of across multiple applications, each with very different business needs.  If I can get this working, it will save me a lot of repeated boiler plate coding down the road.